# Issue with the logic of Php script

Tags: php, forms

I am creating a basic Content Management System for Php practice. Here is a sample code for deleting a post from CMS:

```
<?php

session_start();

include '../DatabaseConnection.php';

if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {

    header('Location:index.php');
    exit();

}

if (isset($_POST['deleteconfirm'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $dbobj = new DBConnect();

    $dbobj -> connect();

    $query = sprintf("delete from `data` where `id` = %d", $id);

    $results = $dbobj -> sqlQuery($query);

    if ($results) {

        $dbobj -> disconnect();
    }

    header('Location:home.php');
    exit();
} elseif (isset($_POST['deletecancel'])) {

    header('Location:home.php');
    exit();

}
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title> Admin Area of CMS ! Delete Post</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="../template/style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="logo">
                <h1><a href="../index.php">CMS</a></h1>
                A minimal Content Management System
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <form action="post-delete.php" method="post">
                    <div id="deletealert">
                        <h3 >You really want to delete this post?</h3>
                        <p>
                            This action cannot be undone !
                        </p>
                        <input type="submit" name="deleteconfirm" value="Yes"/>
                        <input type="submit" name="deletecancel" value="No"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Everything else seems to be working fine, except when I click on deleting a post and then click on "Yes" to confirm, page is redirected to homepage without deleting the actual post.

Any pointers or help appreciated. Let me know if I have missied something important from the context.

**Update:**

The issue was here in the code :

`<form action="post-delete.php" method="post">`

I had to pass the `id` to the script as well from `$id` as below:

`<form action="post-delete.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="post">`

Thanks for the help everyone. The issue is now resolved :)

1> The query was running completely fine before and the post was actually being deleted. Then I added extra confirmation from user in the form of YES/NO.

Also the when the user clicks NO, he is correctly redirected back. It's just when he clicks YES, he's redirected to homepage without actually deleting the post.

2> The `id` field is being passed from the script that handles homepage (home.php). It then calls this page "php-delete.php".

Comment: Try echoing out `$query` to see if it is correct. Also, check with your database library to see if there was an error (insufficient permissions to delete, can't see table, no such table, no such column etc). That said, it is difficult to advise when we don't know what database system you are using - are you using `mysql` or `PDO` or `mysqli`?

Comment: @halfer The $query is all correct. Also no errors in the Database or table. Updating the content a little bit more in the post.

Comment: I don't see where you're sending the id. Shouldn't that be a hidden value in your form retrieved with `$_POST`?

Comment: Well, you're not checking for errors in the code you have shown. There should be a clause that does so, and retrieves the error text from your database library.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,put the header part into the `if` ,so that you are redirected only when the element has been deleted.

```
if ($results) {

        $dbobj -> disconnect();
        header('Location:home.php');
    }
```

At the first time ,this will definitely not redirect you as you should be getting error in your sql query;

use `mysql_error()` in the `else` part to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
```

The change:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

To:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```